# Import Column info from one table to another from non-unique identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, merge, dml

I have two tables, Table A which holds the information I want to pass and Table B I want to accept the information. (19 columns of varchar).

The only column they both hold common is "ItemTitle" (Don't ask, I didn't create it) So I am trying to import based on ItemTitle matching. My problem is in Table A the ItemTitle is unique but on Table B there can be many with the same name.

I want to import the column info to all rows that hold the same ItemTitle not just the first one it finds.

Is it possible to do this?

This is what I tried: (I only used the set for 1 column to see if it worked)
It didn't. Error Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
The multi-part identifier "prodData.ItemTitle" could not be bound.

```
SELECT prodData.[prodID]
      ,prodData.[Item]
      ,prodData.[ParentItem]
      ,prodData.[ItemTitle]
      ,prodData.[15]
      ,prodData.[16]
      ,prodData.[17]
      ,prodData.[18]
      ,prodData.[19]
      ,prodData.[20]
      ,prodData.[21]
      ,prodData.[22]
      ,prodData.[23]
      ,prodData.[24]
      ,prodData.[25]
      ,prodData.[26]
      ,prodData.[27]
      ,prodData.[28]
      ,prodData.[29]
      ,prodData.[30]
      ,prodData.[31]
      ,prodData.[32]
      ,prodData.[33]
    From [database].[dbo].[tbl_ProductInfoDump] as prodData
    Inner Join [database].[dbo].[tbl_ProductFilterDump] as filterData 
    on filterData.ItemTitle = prodData.ItemTitle


Update [database].[dbo].[tbl_ProductInfoDump] set [15] = (Select [15] from [database].[dbo].[tbl_ProductFilterDump] as filterData where filterData.ItemTitle = prodData.ItemTitle)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use an update with join, or update from select (whichever you want to name it).

The idea is to join the destination table (B) with the origin table (A), and make the update taken for each row of B the values of the columns from the joined A row.

You can fidn a good explanation here: [SQL SERVER – UPDATE From SELECT Statement – Using JOIN in UPDATE Statement – Multiple Tables in Update Statement](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/30/sql-server-update-from-select-statement-using-join-in-update-statement-multiple-tables-in-update-statement/). The query looks like this:

```
UPDATE B
SET
   Col1 = A.Col1,
   Col2 = A.Col2
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON A.Title = B.Title
```

Of course, you can include additional filters (`where`clause) to limit the updated rows.